# Calculate the sum of the digits of a number recursively in Python

Tags: python, recursion, sum

I'm having troubles with a recursive function in Python. The objective is for the function to calculate the sum of the digits of a number recursively.

This is what I have so far -- I realise that this version isn't as succinct as it could be, but right now I'm just trying to understand why it isn't working as is:

```
total = 0          #global variable declaration

def digit_sum(n):
    global total   #to be able to update the same variable at every level of recursion
    total += n % 10   #adding the last digit to the total
    n //= 10    #removing the last digit of the number
    if n < 10:
        total += n
        return total
    else:
        digit_sum(n)

print 'The return value of the function is: ', digit_sum(12345)
print 'The final value stored in total is: ', total
```

I obtain the following output:

```
 The return value of the function is:  None
The final value stored in total is:  15
```

My function is somewhat working, since the final value stored in the global variable `total` is correct, but printing the function output returns `None` instead of 15.

Could you please help me understand why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting problem, and an interesting solution! Let me debug with a more simple number - **421**.

1. On first call, `total` is assigned the value `1` and `n` becomes `42`. The `else` branch gets executed.
2. On second call, `total` gets value of `3` and `n` becomes `4`. The `if` branch is executed and the value `total = 7` is `return`ed.

**So, why are we seeing the `None`?** Let's inspect the call-stack:

```
> digit_sum(n = 421)
> > digit_sum(n = 42) # call to digit_sum from inside digit_sum
> -< 7                # value returned by inner/second call
> None
```

As you can notice, the value being returned by the second call is received by the first call, but the **first call doesn't return the value** being returned by the second call, so that's why you are seeing `None`.

**But why does't first call return the value being returned by the second call?**

Because of this line:

```
else:
    digit_sum(n)
```

You are calling the function a second time, but you are not returning its return value.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, I now understand why it wasn't working. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you didn't add a return statement in your else clause.

Adding 'return digit_sum(n)' should solve your problem:

```
if n < 10:
    total += n
    return total
else:
    return digit_sum(n)
```

**Example**

When you have a recursive function (I'll take n! as example), calls are made until you reach a 'base case' (2 in n! and for you if n<10).

Let's take a look at factorial:

```
def fact(n):
    if(n<=2):
        return n
    else:
        return n*fact(n-1)
```

Without the return statement in else clause, if you ask for fact(4), this will also return none.

- Here are the 'calls' with the return statement:

  1. return (4*fact(3))
  2. return (4*(3*fact(2)))
  3. return (4*(3*(2)))

Which gives 24.

- Here are those without:

  1. (4*fact(3))
  2. (4*(3*fact(2)))
  3. (4*(3*(2)))

*So the calculus is made, but nothing is returned.*

I hope this will help you to understand.

NB: [Here](http://www.python-course.eu/recursive_functions.php) is a factorial implementation where recursivity is explained.

Comment: Thank you. That did solve the problem, but to be honest, I'm not understanding why.

Comment: @Baalinooo I tried to explain it with an example, but a way to understand it, is to print intermmediate results.

Comment: The example you added made all the difference helping me understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

my solution is

```
def f(n):
    if n/10 == 0:
         return n
    return n%10 + f(n/10)
```

output:

```
f(12345) = 15
```